# Is it okay to expose your sins for the sake of Jahaliyaah?

Tags: allah, knowing-islam, islamqa

I am aware exposing your sins is forbidden in Islam, however, I’m writing a book that I’d like to advise future Muslims not to make the same mistakes I’ve made. I was wondering if I could tell them what I did in order to prevent them from taking the wrong path in case they stumble upon that road?

I’ve heard of the term, Jahaliyaah but does that justify it’s okay to tell people my sins not for fun but for the sake of preventing them from making the same mistakes I did in the age of ignorance?

Comment: Jahaliyaah means Ignorance. As far as teaching others about avoiding sins is concerned, you don't have to expose yourself. You always use an alias or an analogy to help them differentiate the right path from the wrong.

Comment: Okay, that what I was intending. Jazakhallahukhairun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jahaliyaah means Ignorance.

As far as teaching others about avoiding sins is concerned, you don't have to expose yourself. You can always use an alias or an analogy to help them differentiate the right path from the wrong.